# What was Niven's fix for the problem in "Neutron Star"?

Tags: larry-niven, language-explanation

This is a follow-up to the question ['Unclear meaning of introductory blurb to "Neutron Star"'](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/279842/unclear-meaning-of-introductory-blurb-to-neutron-star), which quotes Niven writing retrospectively "As is, Schaeffer dies. See the collection *Crashlander* for the fix."

Schaeffer, Niven's protagonist, would not have survived on account of a critical aspect of orbital mechanics overlooked in the story (see the linked question's answers.) The above quote suggests that Niven found a way to avoid this problem. If so, I am interested in what it was, and if not, then what did get fixed?

Comment: There are no significant changes in the text from the [1968 release of the story](https://archive.org/details/neutronstar00larr) (in the Anthology "Neutron Star") and the [1994 release of the story](https://archive.org/details/crashlander0000nive) (in the anthology "Crashlander")

Comment: @Valorum Interesting... do you have any idea, then, as to what Niven means by "fix" here?

Comment: Not the foggiest. I was expecting to find some subtle changes to the distances, but it's completely identical aside from a removal of numbers for words ("300 feet" changed to "three hundred feet")

Answer (score 6):

As far as I can see, Niven dealt with two of the three ways that Beowulf Schaffer would have died in "Neutron Star" but not the other.  The ways were:

- Tidal forces spaghettifying him. The extreme tidal forces near a neutron star are powerful enough that no known material -- and certainly not human bodies -- could remain intact, but instead would have been stretched along the axis pointing towards the neutron star until it was a very long, very thin line of specks of human body.
- Radiation from the pulsar. A pulsar's radiation is so strong that even if you accept that the super-high-tech, unobtanium-fueled, never-needs-washing, radiation shield of the GP hull would stop everything it is supposed to stop (very dubious unless it's actually using magic) the gaps in the shield for the visual ranges of client species would let in enough energy to fricassee the contents.  (So Beowulf would have been a very, very long, very, very thin line of vaporized human body.)
- The pulsar's accretion disk: The equatorial plane of most dense, massive object contains a disk of very, very, very, hot gas produced by infalling debris that has too much angular momentum to fall straight in -- a vast majority of infall. The process releases a *lot* of energy which creates the accretion disk from the vaporized debris. Hitting it a a thousand or ten thousand kps would be like hitting a mountain side: Even if the GP hull survived, the contents would be toast. (Making Beowulf into a very, very long, very, very thin, very, very squashed line of vaporized human body.)

In "Ghost: 2", one of a number of bits Niven added between the original Beowulf Schaffer stories, Schaffer takes pains to point out that this was not the first neutron star discovered, but the first *old, cold* one:

> First *old, cold* neutron star...."You couldn't dive that close to a pulsar. Even a GP hull couldn't bash through the accretion disk."

So, there's a plausible solution to everything but the tides.

Comment: As I recall Ghost also comes up with a better justification for the Puppeteers being apparently unaware of tides

Comment: @Andrew yes; they know about tides all along, but used Shaeffers wrong assumptions about their home planet to mislead him about its location. See https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/86264/nivens-neutron-star-plausibility-of-premise.

Comment: Thanks - can't find my copy of Crashlander but the answer you linked matched what I thought I remembered

Comment: I guess I have completely misunderstood "See the collection Crashlander for the fix." I took that to mean that Niven found a way to retell the story in a way that Schaeffer survives, but @valorum says the story is essentially unchanged in Crashlander, and you appear to be saying that the 'fix' Niven is referring to is to say that yes, Schaeffer does die. I do not see how these two responses could be consistent with one another.

Comment: You could ask Larry, but as I recall, in the 70s there was a big discussion on RASSF (in which Niven participated) picking holes -- lots of holes, big and small -- in his Known Space universe, of which the Beowulf Shaffer stories were a part. He responded to the criticisms there but, as I recall, admitted that Schaffer must have died. You may be amused at one of his posts, Down in Flames: https://larryniven.net/stories/downinflames.shtml